# Wordpress - PCI scan - CGI Generic SQL Injection (blind) 80 / tcp / www

Tags: php, wordpress, pci-compliance

I have created new LAMP amazon EC2 instance. (HackerGuardian) PCI scan reported success on the newly built LAMP instance. But after installing wordpress, the same scan reports a failure with High risk (CGI Generic SQL Injection (blind) 80 / tcp / www). Please suggest a fix to patch this vulnerability.

> apache2:   Installed: 2.4.27-2ubuntu3
>
> php:   Installed: 1:7.1+54ubuntu1
>
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS Release:
>   16.04 Codename:       xenial
>
> MYSQL 5.7.19
>
> Latest Version of Wordpress - 4.8.2+dfsg-2